# Apache2 & Cloudflare - Subdomain to Port (with ProxyPass)

Tags: subdomain, apache2, website, cloudflare

I just can not find the mistake .. and need your help.
Sorry for my bad english guys.

My apache2-config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin bl4cklistserver@gmail.com
ServerName citybuild.bl4cklist.de
ProxyPreserveHost On

# setup the proxy
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8123
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8123
```

The subdomain works, but i get a 503 error.

See it live here: [citybuild.bl4cklist.de](https://citybuild.bl4cklist.de)

What must i do? the real directory is on the "8123" port.
I use Dynmap for Minecraft and try to use the map on a subdomain.

Comment: Check Apache's error log. Also, I see a 502 error, not a 503 error.

Comment: I don't have errors in the log from apache2

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed.

I must set a `/` at the end from proxpass and reverse.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin bl4cklistserver@gmail.com
ServerName citybuild.bl4cklist.de
ProxyPreserveHost On

# setup the proxy
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8123/
</VirtualHost>
```